# android dialog call dismiss but is not dismiss

Tags: android

I have a problem with my Android app coding as follows:
I use `dismiss()` to hide a dialog, but dialog just does not disappear as expected. Dialog remains in activity interface while dismiss() is actually called.

It feels like get stucked or something else. Hardware back button does not work either. App just gets stuck in there.
Can anyone help me out
Thanks in advance.

Example pic
[image]
And there are some related code. I use MVP architect.

```html
@Override
    public void editAllNum(Context context, int num, List<ShopCar.GoodListBean> goodList) {
        Subscription s = Observable.just(num)
                .filter(integer -> goodList.size() != 0) //the goodList of size is never equal to 0. 
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
                .compose(TransformerUtil.showLoadingDialog(mView)) //call show dialog.
                .flatMap(new Func1<Integer, Observable<List<ShopCar.GoodListBean>>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<List<ShopCar.GoodListBean>> call(Integer num) {
                        List<ShopCar.GoodListBean> list = new ArrayList<ShopCar.GoodListBean>();
                        for ( ShopCar.GoodListBean item : goodList ) {
                            if ( item.getRemainNum() != 0 ) { 
                                if ( item.getRemainNum() > num ) {
                                    
                                    if ( item.getLimit() != 0 ) {
                                        item = editNum(item, num); //editNum is not important
                                    } else {
                                        item.setNum(num);
                                    }
                                } else {
                                    
                                    if ( item.getLimit() != 0 ) {
                                        item = editNum(item, num);
                                    } else {
                                        item.setNum(item.getRemainNum());
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            list.add(item);
                        }
                        return Observable.just(list);
                    }
                })
                .flatMap(new Func1<List<ShopCar.GoodListBean>, Observable<List<ShopCar.GoodListBean>>>() {
                    @Override
                    public Observable<List<ShopCar.GoodListBean>> call(List<ShopCar.GoodListBean> temp) {
                        return mPaymentImpl.updateGoodsNumAndQuery(context, temp); //operate databases update some data.
                    }
                })
                .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .subscribe(new Subscriber<List<ShopCar.GoodListBean>>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        mView.dismissLoadingDialog();
                    }
                    @Override
                    public void onNext(List<ShopCar.GoodListBean> list) {
                        mView.dismissLoadingDialog();// call dismiss dialog.
                        mView.setShopCarFromDB(list);
                    }
                });
        addSubscription(s);
    }
```

```html
@Override
    public void showLoadingDialog() {
        if ( mLoadingDialog == null ) {
            mLoadingDialog = new LoadingDialog(getContext());
            LogUtils.e(" show loading dialog = " + mLoadingDialog);
        }
        mLoadingDialog.show();
    }

    @Override
    public void dismissLoadingDialog() {
        if ( mLoadingDialog != null ) {
            LogUtils.e(" dismiss loading dialog ");
            mLoadingDialog.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

some code of Dialog.

```html
public class LoadingDialog extends Dialog {



    public LoadingDialog(Context context) {
        super(context, android.R.style.Theme_Translucent);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.widget_loading_dialog);
        setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true);
        setCancelable(true);

    }
}

//XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:background="@drawable/loading_dialog_bg"
        >

        <ProgressBar
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Finally, sorry my English.

Comment: try mLoadingDialog.cancel();

Comment: check if your mLoadingDialog  value is null, maybe it is null and skip the dimiss

Comment: @NikhilSharma i try and dialog can not dismiss too.

Comment: @kggoh i try to note if mLoadingDialog is null, dialog still not disappear

Answer (score 1):

Check if the value of mLoadingDialog is null first. Maybe somehow the value is null. ie. the dialog u see on the screen might not be that mLoadingDialog. By change the function below, what did you see in logcat?

```
@Override
        public void dismissLoadingDialog() {
            if ( mLoadingDialog != null ) {
                LogUtils.e(" dismiss loading dialog ");
                mLoadingDialog.dismiss();
            }else{
               LogUtils.e("mLoadingDialog is null skip dismiss loading dialog ");
           }
        }
```